# Typescript create object of a type which comes from a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, oop

A method returns me a class type: `Widget`.

I want to create a object of this type with the following code:

```
const wType = def.getWidgetType(); // returns Widget as type
const obj = new wType('foo'); // use the const like a normal type with parameters
```

**getWidgetType()**

```
public getWidgetType(): any {
 return TextWidget;
}
```

**Error**

`error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

Is there a "nice" version (without eval) to create a object with a given class type?

Comment: What is the signature of `getWidgetType` ?

Comment: Show us your `getWidgetType`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming what `getWidgetType` returns is a constructor, you can invoke `new wType('foo')` provided the signature of `getWidgetType` explicitly states it returns a constructor signature.

For example this code would be valid:

```
class Definition<T> {
    // Takes in a constructor
    constructor(public ctor: new (p: string) => T) {

    }
    // returns a constructor (aka a function that can be used with the new operator)
    // return type annotation could be inferred here, was added for demonstrative purposes 
    getWidgetType() : new (p: string) => T{
        return this.ctor;
    }
}

const def = new Definition(class {
    constructor(p: string) {}
});

const wType = def.getWidgetType();
const obj = new wType('foo')
```

Comment: Your example helped me to fix my stuff. Thanks! In my code I just had to change the return type to `getWidgetType(): new (id: string) => TextWidget`